# Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ are not the same subfield in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers, field-theory, roots

> Given $f(x) = x^4-2 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$
>
> a) Determine all 4 roots in $\mathbb{C}$
>
> b) Show that there are 2 roots $\alpha$, $\beta$ of $f(x)$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ are not the same subfield in $\mathbb{C}$

a) All I did for this part was find the roots of the equation:

$x^4-2 = 0$

$x^4 = 2$

$x = \sqrt[4]{2}, -\sqrt[4]{2}$

To find all 4 roots, I believe you just need to multiply by $i$, to get the 4 roots:

$x = \sqrt[4]{2}, -\sqrt[4]{2}, i\sqrt[4]{2}, -i\sqrt[4]{2}$

b) For this part, I am not really sure how to approach it. Any guidance would be appreciated. We are given the hint to intersect with $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: To show two subfields are not the same, find a property that one subfield has but the other does not, such as being inside $\mathbf R$.

Comment: How do I find these roots?

Comment: You literally wrote them down in your own question!  Do you realize $\mathbf R$ is a subfield of $\mathbf C$?

Comment: I realize now that $\mathbb{R}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$. To show that b) is true, should I simply state that since $\sqrt[4]{2} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $i\sqrt[4]{2} \in \mathbb{C}$, then they are simply not in the same subfield?

Comment: Also, what is the best way to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ are isomorphic?

Comment: Why do you think those two fields are isomorphic?